# Xcode 7 Could not find a storyboard named

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xcode7

After update Xcode to 7 version, can't build my application. This error is every time when I build in simulator's other versions, and device. After clean project I can run on device, but if I want run again, the error is back.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/43A262C3-81D4-4CF3-B727-AE670906234E/someexample.app> (loaded)'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1852b422c 0x196f280e4 0x18a2f26b0 0x189fbdd48 0x189fbcee0 0x189fbb578 0x18daf53c8 0x18526bfc8 0x18526b0d0 0x1852696f4 0x185194f74 0x189d9c224 0x189d96d94 0x10016854c 0x1975d2a08)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I try to delete from targets "Main Interface" and hardcoding like this in AppDelegate

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
ViewController *yourController = (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartVC"];
self.window.rootViewController = yourController;
```

and I have another error like can't find storyboard ID StartVC

Have u that problem too?

**UPD:**

Try to create new storyboard and put in Main interface and get same error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Storyboard' in bundle NSBundle
```

**UPD 2**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/devBot/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5018D9C0-9609-4368-A72C-488C67EBEFB5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9E485D40-7ED4-4996-942B-81A7C9E4DCA9/someapp.app> (loaded)' with name 'StartVC' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
```

**UPD 3**

In Xcode 6.4 all works fine! I think this is bug in Xcode 7

Comment: Do you have a storyboard file called "Main.storybord" or "Storyboard.storyboard"? If not what is the storybord file called? Can you show a screenshot of the project settings screen. Also, what is the code in application didFinishLaunching... Method.

Comment: Fogmeister, Main.Storyboard. "Storyboard.storyboard" this I create for example. In didFinishLaunching I have nothing about storyboard, and I don't assigned any viewcontrollers to rootviewcontroller

Answer (score 11):

Got this problem with Xcode 7 using storyboard references.
Probably a solution :

- Fix the localisation to be the same for each storyboard in your file inspector (Base, English...). It's probably a problem with the bundle.

Comment: I can't check right now because I create new project and remove all files from old to new, and all work fine. I think problem with .xcodeproj files

Comment: it's works for me. Thanks a lot. it's actually kind of funny theses kind of error. hehhe

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes this happens because the target membership in File Inspector in storyboard is unchecked. Make sure you have that value checked.

Comment: This often happens when you have version control and you are cleaning the project too often.

Comment: No, in target membership storyboard is checked

Answer (score 2):

This suddenly started happening to me, looks like a bug in Xcode 7. I fixed it (possibly only temporarily) by compiling to the iPhone 6 simulator instead of the 6s. We'll see if that is a permanent fix.

To recover, I had to clean the build folder and restart (Quit) Xcode. That solved the problem on 6s for a few compiles.

Comment: Yes, I can compile project only in 5s 8.4 and 5s 9.0, if I want compile to device I need to clean project) And I can run only once! Then I need to repeat my actions!

Comment: If u want change some in storyboard u should Clean project too... its ((((

Comment: Thanks a clean fixed this crash for me. I had used the refactor to storyboard feature.

Answer (score 0):

As an added potential answer, my issue was that my "base.lproj" folder name in the application had a lower case first letter, but Xcode was expecting an uppercase first letter "Base.lproj".

Apparently at some point that got changed ( i could see the casing change in my git change)

I had to edit the project.pbxproj file to replace every occurence of "base" with "Base"

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[NSBundle mainBundle]` just change it to **nil**. Please check my [answer in other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021283/1067147).