# Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle, Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm having troubles with my project after upgrading to XCode 7. When I run I get an error, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle". My storyboard name is Main.storyboard.

If I clean my project it runs just fine. I must clean each time I run or I will get the above error.

If found a number of postings with this same error. The various remedies seem to randomly help some people but not others. So far I have tried the following.

1. Removing the reference to the storyboard in the info.plist file. When I do this the app does start but I get a black screen as it doesn't load the storyboard.
2. Fiddle with the Target Membership Main.storyboard.
3. Remove the storyboard from the project, clean, run and then adding the storyboard back again.
4. Uninstall Xcode, reinstall Xcode.
5. Deleting the Derived Data folder.
6. Loading the Storyboard manually with code such as UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

When I load the storyboard manually it crashes with the same messages as autoloading it.

I saved a copy of my working XCode 6 project before the upgrade and after fussing so much with my project I have tried using a fresh copy of the XCode 6 project that was working but this didn't help.

I've seen a number of posts about this problem where the person just gave up and rebuilt their project from scratch. I'm hoping to avoid this.

[My projects info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFxDC.png)

Comment: Removing the reference to the storyboard from the info.plist works because it doesn't try to load it anymore. Have you tried writing some code that then manually attempts to load it? Secondly, have you tried deleting your derived data?

Comment: Understood on removing the storyboard reference from the info.plist. What I don't' understand is how this fixed this problem for some other users. Perhaps it would cause older version of XCode to use a default name to reference the storyboard and find it.

Comment: I have deleted derived data. I just did it again without success. I'm using the Projects Window to delete the derived data.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: You would need to add this to the AppDelegate --> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: Please help this am also facing this issue after installing the os10.14.1 and xc0de 10.1..am trying to resolve from 3 days but still ..my project works good in xcode9.1..

Answer (score 15):

Can you tried

Select **Target** - > **General** -> **Deployment info** - > **Main interface** "Choose your Storyboard name"

May this help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Please Check Target Membership in your file inspector.

Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same code as follow

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

then just change `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to **nil** and my problems with simulator reinstalls are disappeared.