# Xcode - Did not find storyboard named "MyStoryboard" referenced from Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

This is quite frustrating. I was happily working on `Xcode` project and everything was working fine. All of sudden, when I again ran the project, got this error :

> Did not find storyboard named "MyStoryboard" referenced from
>   Main.storyboard

Haven't touched anything which should bring up this issue. Rather there was no code difference between the code I ran last time and this time.
Now I have gone through [**solutions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634866/xcode-7-could-not-find-a-storyboard-named) suggested (few more as well). But nothing seems to break the ice. Tried these :

1. Clean project, quit Xcode and open again.
2. Removing Xcode's derived data
3. Resetting Main storyboard in project setting

Not at all sure why this happened.

Comment: What exactly is happening? are u seeing the initial VC?

Comment: @SahebRoy : Compile time error

Comment: Xcode version u are using now?

Comment: @SahebRoy : 8.2

Comment: clear derived data and then try cleaning and running the app

Comment: @SahebRoy : Please read my complete question, including what I have tried.

Comment: Can you post the code in `applicationDidLaunchWithOptions`, if you can

Comment: @SahebRoy : Sure, only if you share, how that might help.

Comment: If you have a backup of this project then open it and see the same problem exists or not.

Comment: @OP If there is any window related code, where you manually switch the window to force another storyboard to open instead of sticking with the initial controller, this might happen. Xcode is surely getting a reference of "MyStoryboard" from somewhere, and you got to track it down.

Answer (score 19):

I also had this issue, and solved it by checking target from my ViewController.

[image]

Comment: Great !!Thanks this solution fixed my issue.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I tried like you all the suggested solutions but it was not enough. 
My problem was the some of my storyboards were localized, and some others not. So by localizing all my storyboard it resolved the issue. 
I guess it's because it's now in the same folder.

Comment: I realized some storyboards were inside a `*.lproj` folder while others weren't. I had to move all storyboards into that folder – then it worked. Thanks for think!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles across this in the future: the issue for me was that while I had moved/re-added/un-localized a Storyboard file, when it was re-imported it did not get added back to the main target of my app, so check that too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by making sure the Localization checks had a match between the two storyboards:

[image: Storyboard Localization]